# xymon won't display cpu, disk, memory and other system parameters

Tags: amazon-ec2, dashboard, monitor

I have setup xymon on my ubuntu EC2 instance,but my web monitor is not showing columns for disk, memory, cpu and other important parameters as shown below except for the main xymon server:

[image]

Below is my xymon server hosts.cfg config:

```
#group Servers
127.0.0.1       xymon-1043-cnnxdv.aylacnnxdv.net        # bbd http://xymon-1043-cnnxdv.aylacnnxdv.net/
172.*.*.11    mysql-general-11011      # CLIENT:client ssh mysql:3306 NOCOLUMNS:ports,files
172.*.*.12    mysql-general-12011      # CLIENT:client ssh mysql:3306 NOCOLUMNS:ports,files
172.*.*.13    mysql-general-11011      # CLIENT:client ssh mysql:3306 NOCOLUMNS:ports,files
172.*.*.14    cass-11022-cnnxdv        # CLIENT:client ssh cassandra:7000 NOCOLUMNS:ports,files
172.*.*.13    cass-12022-cnnxdv        # CLIENT:client ssh cassandra:7000 NOCOLUMNS:ports,files
172.*.*.14    cass-13022-cnnxdv        # CLIENT:client ssh cassandra:7000 NOCOLUMNS:ports,files
```

How can i get the system specs (cpu, disk, memory etc) showing on the symon node also show on other nodes as well?

Comment: This comes in pretty late, but maybe it helps: remove the "CLIENT:client" statements from each entry. "CLIENT:" is used, if your client reports a different hostname than its name in xymon (second column in hosts.cfg). Furthermore I'm not sure, if the asterisks in the IP columns are right, I've never seen this before. If it works, xymon has a lot to test, because there are 255^2 possible combinations. Interestingly the ssh-column works, so xymon has detected something...

Comment: "mysql:3306" and "cassandra:7000" are also no valid statements in the hosts.cfg. I see what you want to do, but xymon does not offer tests for connecting to these services. The easiest solution in my opinion would be to add "PROC mysql" and "PORT LOCAL=%[.:]3306$ STATE=LISTEN TEXT=MYSQL" in your analysis.cfg. This way you have to remove "ports" from you "NOCOLUMNS" statement in hosts.cfg.